# Accessing JavaScript object correctly after receiving it from JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, socket.io

I have a JSON file, which contains some data (in this case: 4 different items.
AFTER I parse the JSON file I get the output seeing below.
Now I have a javascript object, am I correct?

I want to access each Item now, and I want to add every item to a plain Object.
So how do I add it to the plain object?
It should look like that I think:

```
obj = [
    { id: 0, value: 'cas', date: '', tags: '' },
    { id: 1, value: '', date: 'vcxyv', tags: '' },
    ...
]
```

(afterward, I'm rendering these object to get a list on my web application)

[image]

Comment: What did you try? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp :)

Comment: Do you look for `var obj = response.expArray`? Where `reponse` is what you have in the screenshot.

Comment: You cannot convert array object to single plan object

Comment: @Rashomon `w3schools` sources are not up to date. you should use `mdn`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or any other updated source

Comment: @CodeManiac Enough info to give it a try, but good to know :)

Comment: @Sascha you can't convert an array composed on index & value to object.But you can try to create object with key,value pair where key is your "id" and value is each single object like `obj = {"0":{  value: 'cas', date: '', tags: '' },"1:"{ id: 1, value: '', date: 'vcxyv', tags: '' }...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, thank u guys. I got it!

```
var obj = require('./expenses.json').expArray;
console.log(obj);

for (var key in obj) {
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

    expArr[key] = obj[key];
   }
}
console.log(expArr);
```

here i my output now in the style of @tvankith

[image]